# Plot variable of xarray in a map

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I have the following xarray and I would like to plot the variable `pr` in a map. The problem is that `pr` depends on `station` (object), which in turn depends on the coordinates  `x`and  `y` (float).

The code I am trying to use is:

```
ds.pr[0].plot()
```

But it does not work because it is getting the coordinate `station` instead of `x`and  `y`.

[image: Description of xarray]

Comment: What does station actually refer to? My guess is the netCDF file is storing point data, not gridded data. In this case plot will not work no matter what you try to do.

Comment: Station is a name that identifies every tuple of x and y. And you are right that it is storing point data, but it is possible to plot it as you can see in the official documentation: https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/multidimensional-coords.html

Comment: The examples there only show plotting gridded data, not point. My advice here would be to convert the data to pandas dataframes and plot it from there

Comment: Okay, I guess that will work too! Thanks!

Comment: yeah you might be able to do `ds.isel(time=0).plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', hue='pr')` but that's pretty similar to `ds.pr.isel(time=0).to_series().plot(x='x', y='y')` at that point